# Db2: how to format output?

Tags: db2

I don't like the db2 console output

```
db2 => SELECT city,SUM(sales) as sum from offices group by city;

CITY                                                                                            SUM                              
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------
Rome                                                                                                                        14000,
London                                                                                                                         19000,
```

I would prefer something like this

```
db2 => SELECT city,SUM(sales) as sum from offices group by city;

CITY                           SUM                              
------------------------
Rome                           14000
London                         19000
```

On Oracle I use

```
set feedback on;
set linesize 9000
set  colsep |
column column1 format a30
column column2 format a20
....
```

And I get a nice output
How for format the columns on DB2?
I'm interested in max size(a30 mean display 30 chars).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formatting of SQL output is a job for the client application.

Your question shows use of the legacy interactive Db2 Command-Line-Processor (Db2 CLP) application supplied with some Db2 clients.  The Db2 CLP has limited formatting functionality compared to Oracle SQL*Plus.

However, if you are used to Oracle `SQL*Plus` style formatting, there is a tool supplied with some Db2 clients called [clpplus](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.clpplus.doc/doc/c0053823.html) which emulates `SQL*Plus`. This means you don't need to learn new syntax for formatting and many other actions.

You can use `clpplus` instead of the interactive Db2 CLP, and `clpplus` lets you use many of the features and syntax of Oracle `SQL*Plus` with Db2 databases.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a nice workaround using substr of SQL syntax

Without substr

```
select title,year from titles;

TITLE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       YEAR                  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------
Fantasia                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           1940
```

EEK!

With using of substr

```
select substr(title,1,19) as title, substr(year,1,4) as year from titles;

TITLE                                  YEAR
-------------------------------------- ----
FANTASIA                               1940
```

Good!